# How to keep a one-to-one relationship between polymorphic classes in different layers?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, polymorphism, factory

I have a domain logic layer in which an abstract superclass exists, let's call it *DomainAbstractClass*.

Many concrete classes inherit from this class, let's call them *ConcreteDomainClass1*, *ConcreteDomainClass2* and so on.

Now, in a different assembly, which is my presentation logic layer, I have a similar hierarchy in which an abstract super class, let's call it *PresentationAbstractClass*, is implemented by many concrete classes *ConcretePresentationClass1*, *ConcretePresentationClass2* and so on.

There is a natural one-to-one relationship between *ConcreteDomainClass1* and *ConcretePresentationClass1*, *ConcreteDomainClass2* and *ConcretePresentationClass2*, etc... since the presentation classes encapsulate the specific presentation logic of each specific domain entity.

Since I want to keep my domain logic layer as dependency free as possible, **my presentation logic layer has a reference to the domain logic layer, but not the other way around.**

Now, the presentation logic layer calls a method in the domain logic layer that returns an *AbstractDomainClass*, and I need to create the appropiate *ConcretePresentationClassN* according to the *ConcreteDomainClassN* that the abstract domain class really is.

Is there a creational pattern that allows me to accomplish this without having to resort to this ugly thing?

```
if(abstractClass is ConcreteDomainClass1)
    new ConcretePresentationClass1();

else if (abstractClass is ConcreteDomainClass2)
    new ConcretePresentationClass2();

// ... and so on
```

Comment: Since you mention the 1-1 relationship between Presentation & Business layer objects, why not keep all interfaces using the base class and cast to the correct type in the presenter?

Comment: How does the domain logic determine which domain class to return? Maybe that logic could potentially be lifted out of the domain layer?

Comment: Sriram, the above code is not an actual snippet from my real code, I was just trying to convey the idea that all we know about the variable is that it an _AbstractDomainClass_

Comment: Rob, the type of domain class depends on values stored in a database, so the type of domain class is determined way below. Couldn't possibly lift that logic to the presentation layer.

Comment: Marvin, could you please elaborate a bit on your comment? What base class are you refering to? what do you mean with 'keep all interfaces using the base class'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the factory pattern by wrapping the whole thing up in a simple factory method and use a dictionary to map between the classes:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Func<DomainAbstractClass, PresentationAbstractClass>> factory = 
    new Dictionary<Type, Func<DomainAbstractClass, PresentationAbstractClass>>
    {
        { typeof(ConcreteDomainClass1), (x) => new ConcretePresentationClass1(x) },
        { typeof(ConcreteDomainClass2), (x) => new ConcretePresentationClass2(x) },
        ....
    };

public PresentationAbstractClass ObtainPresentationClassFromDomainClass(DomainAbstractClass domainClass)
{
    return factory[domainClass.GetType()](domainClass);
}
```

Comment: David, thanks for the answer. The creation logic of the presentation object, however, not only depends on the type of the domain logic class but also on the values and properties of the domain logic class.

Comment: @edivila I have updated my answer to meet such a need. The domain class is now passed to the presentation class' constructor. Your exact needs may be different, the only thing to ensure is that `PresentationAbstractClass` defines a public constructor in order to define a suitable constructor signature for the factory.

Comment: Thanks. What I was originally aiming at was for a way to avoid conditional logic on the type of the concrete domain class, which is still present in your code. I'm almost sure that there is no way around this though. Anyway, your code is a good idea, and a lot neater than my if-else chain, so I might end up using it, so thanks again! :)

Comment: @edivila If you want to keep the layers separated (and I agree, you do want to do that as it's excellent practice), then somewhere, somehow you have to map the classes. You could go to extremes and use string substitution on the class names and reflection to avoid any sort of mapping, but that would make your code unintuitive for little gain. Wrapping that matching mechanism up in a factory class helps. I personally think the dictionary approach is easier to read and maintain than lots of if statements, but you are right that it is effectively the same code, just expressed differently.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is as follows:

> ```
>  ---Presentation layer---   ---Domain layer---   ---Repository layer---
> 1.  --- control flow --->    --- control flow--->   --- control flow---
> 2.  --- creation of PO---   <-- creation of DO --    <----- data -----|
> ```

where *creation of DO* is the creation of a particular domain object, and *creation of PO* is the creation of a particular presentation object, which depends on domain object type, which depends on the data.

Unavoidably, this chain of dependencies makes the type of the desired presentation object dependent transitively on the data. This is somehow a normal case, but the creation control flow here seems to be some kind of an ill-conditioning for this pattern. Usually the "creation chain" is like this: a *View* instantiates (or references) a *ViewModel* which references a particular *Model*.

Thus the only solution (not considering redesign) is to use some kind of registry/factory which create appropriate presentation object depending on domain object's type. Which unfortunately is equivalent to switching on object's type.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. What I get is that you want to create a presentation class, based on input from another presentation class, that is being processed by domain class.

If you want it to be magically resolved / generated, there are some IOC Container out there who can help you to resolve the concrete class by logic and configuration (AutoFac, Simple Injector, Castle Windsor, etc). However I don't has any experience so I cannot share much (but I know those container has the ability for the configuration).

For your starting point, the technique is named `Convention over Configuration`, used by Asp.Net MVC controller - view resolver.

However, this is the manual logic by using reflection:

```
public AbstractFactory{
    public AbstractFactory (IConfiguration config){
        this.presentationClassNameSpace = config.PresentationClassNameSpace;
    }
    private readonly string presentationClassNameSpace;
    public AbstractPresentationClass Resolve(Type t){
        string className = t.Name;
        className = className.Replace("Domain", "Presentation");
        AbstractPresentationClass resultClass = 
            (AbstractPresentationClass) System.Activator.CreateInstance(
                Type.GetType(presentationClassNameSpace + "." + className);
        return resultClass;
    }
}
```

Note:

You can use generic type instead of Type t if you want to inject the `AbstractDomainClass`, and based on the injected object you get the type by `GetType();`. The advantage is you can create another abstract factory with specific method from give concrete domain class.

Or you can inject `AbstractDomainClass` instead and get the type by `GetType();`.

You can use generic at method level to resolve the type as you wish if you want, however I do not recommend it.